# Proving that two equations are the same

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Where am I doing it wrong?
Both of them should be simplified to ***$ A \cup (B \cap C)$***

---

1$$ A \cup (B \cap (A \cup C) ) =  A \cup (A \cup B^c)^c) \cap (A\cup C)$$
2$$ A \cup ((B \cap A)\cup(B \cap C)) = A  \cup (A^c \cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$$
3$$ (A \cup (B \cap A )) \cup  (A  \cup (B \cap C)) = ((A  \cup A^c )\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$$
4$$ A \cup (B \cap C) = B\cap (A\cup C)$$

Comment: The normal argument is element chasing. That is assume $x$ is a member of the set on the left hand side and prove it is an element of the right hand side. Do the same assuming that $x$ is an element of the right hand side. If both hold the sides must be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind; I have solved it now. 
I was applying De Morgan's Laws incorrectly. 
$$A∪((B∩A)∪(B∩C))=A∪(A^c∩B)∩(A∪C)$$